# Delay when send data to peripheral with Core Bluetooth&

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, core-bluetooth

I work with a Bluetooth peripheral. When I connect, I subscribe to its characteristics and get a huge amount of data. The data comes without delay. There is no delay when sending data to the device. After 5 minutes of use, there is a delay in sending data to the device for 30 seconds. After 10 minutes of use, there is a delay in sending data to the device for 2 minutes and so on. Tried at the time of sending instantly unsubscribe from the characteristics-did not help. Tried to do everything without the interface-did not help. Who faced such problem? Is there a solution?

Comment: I have made an app that communicates over bluetooth LE and that stays connected for a long time. We have never noticed an issue with delay in either direction, so I don't think the issue is related to iOS. I suspect the issue lies on the pheripheral side. I suggest that you get a Bluetooth LE sniffer so that you can see exactly what goes on on the BT link.

Comment: @Anton if I am connected to the device and do not subscribe to the characteristics. There is no delay when sending data to the device. And if I receive data from the device, the delay increases.

Comment: "And if I receive data from the device, the delay increases." Maybe there is some enqueing, either from the peripheral (too much thing to do with limited hardware?) or on your side. But that's hard to know what's going on.